# Using Log4Net With Remote Processes

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have many processes logging to one file ?

I ve looked at the API with no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log4net [FAQ](http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#multiProcess):

> The FileAppender holds a write lock on
>   the log file while it is logging. This
>   prevents other processes from writing
>   to the file, therefore it is not
>   possible to have multiple processes
>   log directly to the same log file,
>   even if they are on the same machine.
>
> You may have each process log to a
>   RemotingAppender. The receiving
>   RemoteLoggingServerPlugin (or
>   IRemoteLoggingSink) can receive all
>   the events and send them to a single
>   log file.